# `vp-preview-invisible` class is added to the preview thumbnail in Safari, but not in Chrome in vimeo embedded video

Tags: css, class, iframe, safari, vimeo

I am embedding a video on my page using the vimeo player.

For some reasons the thumbnail of the video has the class `vp-preview-invisible` in Safari (which makes the thumbnail invisible), but the class is absent in Chrome (which makes the thumbnail visible).

**Chrome**

[image]

```
<div class="vp-preview vp-preview-cover" ... </div>
```

**Safari**

[image]

```
<div class="vp-preview vp-preview-cover vp-preview-invisible" ... </div>
```

Here is the video id which I am talking about: **326869440**.

I need the thumbnail to be visible in both Chrome and Safari.

I am using the `Version 12.0.1 (13606.2.104.1.2)` for Safari.

How could I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @ZF007, ok, let me retype. (y)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. What version of safari are you using? How are you embedding the video (code)? when you go to the player embed page player.vimeo.com/video/[CLIP-ID], do you see the same issue? That clip ID is appearing as private to me-  do you have a different one to test with?

Comment: @RebeccaSich, could you, please, test [here](https://www.scarosso.com/en/shoe-guide-landing/philosophy/?HPFlyoutE1_dsk_27032019_shoe-guide-philosophy=1) ? I provided the Safari version in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @RebeccaSich, hello. Are you still there? ( :

Comment: I have the same issue, and I can't seem to target that class to remove it, even with muted=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@YaroslavTrofimov According to the site you linked I was able to see that you are using this to embed the player `https://player.vimeo.com/video/326869440?autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0`.

I see the problem. It is the use of the `autoplay=1` param. Autoplay has a lot of rules depending on the browser, some browsers handle it better and some handle it worse. Essentially, all browsers are now attempting to block UNMUTED Autoplay. (This is because users hated when they opened a site and audio would start playing out of nowhere.) They will allow your video to autoplay if it is muted though. So when you add `muted=1` it will work. However this video has important audio content so you don't want to do that.

So what is the problem? When you use `autoplay=1` the Vimeo player attempts to play it. However, the browser will interject and pause it moments later (because it doesn't allow autoplay with sound and it hasn't registered a user clicking play). When the Vimeo player attempts to play we always hide the thumbnail. The fact that it was paused by the browser, instead of a user clicking pause, is irrelevant and unknown to the player. The same way that when you click play and then later click pause, we don't show the thumbnail again. That is what is happening.

So you may wonder why Chrome and Safari differ. I think it's just a matter of how fast they detect your autoplay attempt and when they stop it. Because each browser is doing it on their own, we can't control that.

Lastly, how can you fix it? Well, that's the hard thing. The simplest fix is to get rid of the `autoplay=1` param. If you want it to autoplay when it can (some browsers are more lenient in certain cases), then you're kind of out of luck on Safari.

Hope that answers your question.