# How to fix Vimeo thumbnails on iOS when using multiple players on one page?

Tags: html, css, ios, vimeo

I have three Vimeo players on one page. On all desktop browsers the video thumbnail / poster frame is visible, but on iOS I can only see one player with a thumbnail and two black players. All three are working though.

In the iframe of the player that has a thumbnail, I can see a div with the classname "vp-preview" which has a data-thumb and a style inline tag. The url to the thumbnail is stored in the data-thumb and is set as a background-image in the style inline.

In the iframes of the players that don't have a thumbnail, the vp-preview div only has a data-thumb inline tag with the url to the thumbnail, but no style inline.

When I delete the Vimeo player in the web inspector and then undo this, the player is reloaded and now the thumbnail is showing in iOS.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`vp-preview-invisible\` class is added to the preview thumbnail in Safari, but not in Chrome in vimeo embedded video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592950/vp-preview-invisible-class-is-added-to-the-preview-thumbnail-in-safari-but-no)

Comment: Yes that does answer it. A few days earlier I also discovered the link you posted and added it as an answer to this question, but this post has been deleted.